# Cannot install 'shiny' either 'bslib' package

Tags: r, installation, shiny, updates, phylogeny

I am trying to install the package 'phylosignal' and I have some errors related to the installation of 'shiny' and 'bslib' packages. I have tried several solutions I found but none of them have worked properly. I have updated all my packages but, still, some of them remains an uploaded (e.g. 'htmlttols).

Any suggestions? I am stuck here.

I work on windows and my RStudio version is updated to the last version.

This is my console:

```
> library(phylosignal)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phylosignal’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘shiny’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘phylosignal’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
> install.packages("shiny")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("shiny")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jmtorresruiz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘sass’, ‘htmltools’, ‘rlang’, ‘bslib’, ‘cachem’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary  source needs_compilation
sass        0.2.0   0.3.1              TRUE
htmltools   0.4.0 0.5.1.1              TRUE
rlang       0.4.5  0.4.10              TRUE
shiny     1.4.0.2   1.6.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘cachem’
  These will not be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sass_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3430000 bytes (3.3 MB)
downloaded 3.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/htmltools_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 690367 bytes (674 KB)
downloaded 674 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘sass’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jmtorresruiz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDt8Ko\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘bslib’, ‘shiny’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3481982 bytes (3.3 MB)
downloaded 3.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/shiny_1.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4170497 bytes (4.0 MB)
downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.4.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/jmtorresruiz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/bslib'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'bslib', 'cachem' are not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/jmtorresruiz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/shiny'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\jmtorresruiz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDt8Ko\downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("bslib")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jmtorresruiz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘htmltools’, ‘sass’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary  source needs_compilation
htmltools  0.4.0 0.5.1.1              TRUE
sass       0.2.0   0.3.1              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/htmltools_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 690367 bytes (674 KB)
downloaded 674 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sass_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3430000 bytes (3.3 MB)
downloaded 3.3 MB

package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sass’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jmtorresruiz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDt8Ko\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘bslib’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3481982 bytes (3.3 MB)
downloaded 3.3 MB

* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.4.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/jmtorresruiz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/bslib'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\jmtorresruiz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDt8Ko\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: It say that you need `htmltools 0.5.1`, have you updated this package ? If not, you can install it from github I guess, have you tried this ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to solve it by installing htmltools 0.5.1 but it did not work. At the end, I have to uninstall and re-install again RStudio with all the packages I use to use. It was the only thing it worked. A bit drastic, but effective.